# Best way to run separate parts of a single T-SQL script together at once

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, refactoring

I have a some long scripts that have variables at the very top.  When I want to run only part of the script with a variable included, what is the best way to do this...are there **other** options besides:

1. Copy/pasting the declare variables (but this requires me to comment
   them in/out all the time)
2. Just changing the variable to be hard-coded (but I'm concerned that I'll forget to change them back)

So, is there a way to highlight separately the parts I want to run...or maybe something else entirely?

This question is for SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the other answers are fine if you can/want to make functional modifications to your script, but if you would rather avoid that, as I suspect, the way I usually do what you are talking about is by block-commenting the parts I want to skip:

So I just change this:

```
DECLARE @variables;

Some Code I want to skip this time;

Some Code I want to execute this time;

Maybe some more code I want to skip this time;
```

To this:

```
DECLARE @variables;
/*
Some Code I want to skip this time;
*/
Some Code I want to execute this time;
/*
Maybe some more code I want to skip this time;
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I wrap portions of the code inside `BEGIN...END` blocks so that I could expand and collapse them inside SSMS. Turns out that you can prefix a block with an `IF 0 = 1` so that it does not execute. Expanding on this idea, you could do this:

```
-- variables
DECLARE @p1 INT = 123;
DECLARE @p2 INT = 456;

-- which block to run
DECLARE @block AS INT = 1;

IF @block = 1
BEGIN
    SELECT 'statement block 1'
END

IF @block = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT 'statement block 2'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use a special variable that I call `@debug`, but you can call it what you want. When I'm debugging, I'll use it to set variables, raise status messages (disguised as error messages), and that sort of thing. Then I only need to remember to reset that one value when I'm finished.

```
DECLARE 
  @var1 INT,
  @var2 VARCHAR(25),
  @var3 BIGINT,
  @debug TINYINT,   --Indicator that I'm in debug mode
  @msg VARCHAR(50); --Custom message text placeholder

SET @debug = 1;

IF @debug = 1
  BEGIN
    SELECT
      @var1 = 1,
      @var2 = 'Hello World',
      @var3 = 12;
  END;

SELECT @var1, @var2, @var3;

IF @debug = 1
  BEGIN
    SET @msg = 'Step 1 Complete'
    RAISERROR(@msg, 1,0) WITH NOWAIT
  END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use conditionals. See @RunOne and @RunTwo for explanation.

```
DECLARE @MessageText as varchar(28) = 'This is not a greeting'

Declare @RunOne as bit = 1 -- set to 0 to skip first part
Declare @RunTwo as bit = 1 -- set to 0 to skip second part

IF @RunOne = 1
BEGIN
   select @MessageText + ', or is it?'
END

IF @RunTwo = 1
BEGIN
   select @MessageText + ' for wide dissemination.'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Just building on Salman's answer (+1).

This twist will allow for a block range rather than just one at a time.

**Example**

```
-- Declare Your Variables
Declare @V1 int = 8;
Declare @V2 int = 12;

-- Define which Blocks to Execute  
Declare @BlockRange1 int = 3
Declare @BlockRange2 int = 4


If 1 between @BlockRange1 and @BlockRange2
Begin
    Select 1 
End

If 2 between @BlockRange1 and @BlockRange2
Begin
    Select 2
End

If 3 between @BlockRange1 and @BlockRange2
Begin
    Select 3
End

If 4 between @BlockRange1 and @BlockRange2
Begin
    Select 4
End
```

Answer (score 1):

You can label each part of your query and use [GOTO](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/goto-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) clause Like this :

```
    --Chose Witch Block To Run 
    DECLARE @ControlFlag SMALLINT = <YourChoose>
    IF ControlFlag = 1 GOTO PART1 ELSE GOTO PART2
    PART1:
    DECLARE @v1 INT,@v2 INT

    PART2:
    DECLARE @v3 INT,@v4 INT
```